# Поиск по массиву

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Есть проблема с поиском по массиву. Задача следующая. Массив создается из файла.

```
$file_array = file("email.php");
```

Фаил содержит емайлы. Далее нужно выполнить поиск. Передается переменная с емайлом. Далее должно быть такое условие: если емаил в массиве существует, то вывести "регистрация запрещена", если емайла в массиве нет, то вывести "регистрация разрешена". Целый день читаю мануалы по поиску в массивах приведенные в них функции `array_search()` и `in_array()` не работают. Подскажите, как мне реализовать этот поиск?

Answer (score 2):

Что значит: **"не работает?"** ? Две данные функции работают практически идентично: обе ищут в массиве значение, но только первая возвращает ключ, а вторая результат поиска( true/false ). Обе функции используют одинаковый алгоритм поиска и обеим требуется линейное время для поиска любого элемента. Ну вот ненужный пример:

```
$arr = array("1","2","3","4");
$val = array_search("4",$arr);  // 3
$bool = in_array("4",$arr); // true
```

Comment: Это значит, результат использования не оправдывает ожидания. Как показывает практика, скорее всего дело в неправильной подготовке данных.

Comment: Да, мне тоже так показалось...

Comment: Функция не работает тоже

Comment: @alexsis20102 - либо учитесь дебажить, либо вам на фриланс

Answer (score 1):

```
function trimmer(&$v,$k){
  $v = trim($v);
}

$EMAIL = $_GET['user_input_email'];

$file_array = file("email.php");
$file_array = array_flip($file_array);
array_walk($file_array,'trimmer');
if(isset($file_array[$EMAIL])){
  print 'registration not available';
}
```

Comment: мне кажется или это костыль? :D

Comment: Все равно почему то реакции нет (((

Comment: @AlexWindHope, это мегасуперпуперпрепроцессорный костыль. А что делать?

Comment: @alexsis20102, скопируйте сюда кусок файла, пожалуйста. Можете буквы заменить звездочками, но не трогайте пробелы и переносы строк.

Comment: @knes, значит мой ответ еще никого не переубедил? ))) Хочется еще покапаться? Ню-ню...

Comment: @knes - что делать написал @Asen, а это просто ппц

@Deonis - а в чем он должен убедить? @knes, пускай и страшным образом, но trim делает, у аффтара все-равно не работает

Простите, даже если предположить, что в файле есть полностью пустые строки - чем тут поможет `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`?

"Разницу в результате увидите сами" - еще раз повторюсь. `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`, в этом случае, делает тот-же trim

Comment: @AlexWindHope, пусть аффтар проверит мой способ и я уверен на 99,9% , что заработает. Для полной уверености, можно добавить еще один флаг: FILE\_SKIP\_\EMPTY\_LINES

@knes, был прав вот в чем

> скорее всего дело в неправильной подготовке данных.

@AlexWindHope, то есть логичней прошуршать весь массив с помощью trim, чем вытащить сразу подготовленные данные?

Comment: @Deonis - я не писал что это логичнее, я лишь намекаю на то, что, если код, предложенный @knes 'ом, не помог, то и вам не поможет

Вы вообще мой первый комментарий к ответу смотрели или не?

Comment: @Deonis, да, это дает большую вероятность избежать неприятных ситуаций с пробелами ДО или после адресов. Еще не удивлюсь, если там вообще нет ни одного переноса строк.

Comment: > Еще не удивлюсь, если там вообще нет ни одного переноса строк.

@knes, хм... Со своей колокольни, я даже это предположить не мог )) А ведь действительно, что и такое может быть ))

Answer (score 0):

Всё предельно просто - про флажки не забываем ;)

```
$file_array = file("email.php", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$new_mail = 'mutin-pudak@mail.ru';

if(in_array($new_mail, $file_array)){
    echo 'Чаво-то нашли!';
} else {
    echo 'Фонарь! Мыло не найдено!';
}
```

Цитата из мануала:

> FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES
>     Не добавлять новую строку к концу каждого элемента массива

**UPD**
Психонул и создал файл, как у ТС email.php, в котором прописал (утрированно)

```
mail_1@mail.ru

mail_2@mail.ru

mail_3@mail.ru

mutin-pudak@mail.ru
```

И файлик index.php, в котором код из моего примера выше. Теперь, попробуйте
запустить без флага и с ним. Разницу в результате увидите сами ))